# Ruby MIME::Multipart error

Tags: ruby, mime-types

Here are the gems i have installed 
mime (0.4.2)
mime-types (2.5)
mimemagic (0.2.1)
multipart-post (2.0.0)

When trying to do a command to create a new multipart mime within my console

```
@msg = MIME::Multipart::Mixed.new
```

i get these errors.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MIME::Multipart
    from /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@project/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:466:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
    from /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@project/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@project/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing_with_dependencies'
    from /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@project/gems/mime-types-2.5/lib/mime.rb:40:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):7
    from /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation of the gem is only part if it, you need to require it before you can use it.

```
require 'mime'
```

Just tried it:

```
2.2.0 :001 > require 'mime'
 => true 
2.2.0 :002 > msg = MIME::Multipart::Mixed.new
 => #<MIME::Multipart::Mixed:0x007ff15c0e06f0 ...
```

Comment: Interesting 

I just tried that and im  still being presented with and error

>> require 'mime'
=> []
>> @msg = MIME::Multipart::Mixed.new
NameError: uninitialized constant MIME::Multipart

Comment: What are you doing this in?  irb?  Where did you install the gems?  It seems like you are using RVM with a gemset, are they in there?

Comment: Yes i am doing this with RVM   Ruby 1.9.3  Rails 2.3.18

Comment: Oh so it's Rails?  Are you doing this in the `rails console`?  Have you added those gems to your `Gemfile`? Or did you just `gem install` them?

Comment: i just installed the gem within RVM. not added to gem file.   currently not using a bundle either.

Comment: Are you using the rails console though?  It won't work if you don't add it to the gemfile and are using rails.

Comment: Not using a bundle so there will be no gemfile.  i am using the ruby console direct yes.

Multipart::mixed does work on the older version correct?

Comment: If you are using rails you are using Bundler. Not a bundle, I don't know what that is in Ruby. Bottom line you need it required, Bundler does it for you if you are using it. Best of luck!